# What's the pattern of the noise curves in these captcha images?

Tags: python, image-processing, captcha, photoshop, gimp

I want to mimic and reproduce the noise curves in the captcha images below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It seems the curve was generated by a brush on a random curve path.
The pattern of the path is like but not simple sin/cos function or a Bessel function.

So, how can I guess the curve paths' pattern?

Comment: You may be better off fitting a polynomial curve. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting#Fitting_lines_and_polynomial_curves_to_data_points

Comment: @rayryeng I don't think it's a polynomial function.

Comment: Never said it was. I said you "may be better off".  From some of those images it looks like it, but I can't honestly say for sure.  The only thing I can really suggest is try it and see how it goes.  It could also be piecewise polynomial too.  Split up the segments into polynomials of different orders!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Quite helpful. I'd give a try. @rayryeng

Comment: No problem at all.  More on what I was suggesting, figure out how many segments you want to split up the width of the image into, then for each segment, generate a spline or polynomial of a random order and random coefficients... also make sure that the end of one spline serves as the beginning of the next spline and piece them all together.  If that works, I wouldn't mind writing an answer and probably with a Python implementation too!  Let me know how it goes.